# if $a!\cdot b!|n!$ prove $a+b<n+c\ln{\ln{n}}$

Tags: number-theory

Prove that there exists an absolute constant $c$ such that for any positive integers $a,b,n$ for which $$a!\cdot b!|n!,1<a<b<n$$
we have $$a+b<n+c\ln\ln{n}.$$
It is  said the stronger is creat by Erdos.and I have found the easy upper $O(\ln{n})$,But I can't prove $O(\ln{\ln{n}})$.Thanks

I have know this following easy problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are $v_2$ and $s_2$?

Comment: Why do you think that the stronger claim is also true?

Comment: $v_{p}(a)$ is the expoent of the prime number $p$ in the prime factorization of $a$,and  $s_{p}(n)$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ when written in base $p$

Comment: @DietrichBurde,I have add this problem,this book can't  no answer

Comment: Do you know the title of the book or article which this problem came from?

Comment: @AngelaPretorius maybe I missed something, but it seems that your (deleted) answer nearly worked; you just needed to interchange $a$ and $b$. See below. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

Take $a \ge 3$, and let $b = a!-1$ and $n = a!$. Then $a!b! = a!(a!-1)! = a!! = n!$ and $a < b < n$, while, for any fixed $c > 0$, if $a$ is large enough we have $$n+c\log\log(n)-a-b = a!+c\log\log(a!) -a-(a!-1)$$ $$\le c\log(\log(a^a))-a+1$$ $$\le c\log(a\log a)-a+1 \le 2c\log(a)-a+1 < 0.$$ We conclude that your stronger question is false.

This examples gives $a+b = n+c\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}$.

I wonder if there's an example of $a!\cdot b! \mid n!$ and $a+b = n+\Omega(\log n)$.

Comment: The stronger question is false, but P19 is not false in your example; in your example, $n = b + 1$, so certainly $n < b + c \log \log n$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov oh what the heck. i thought P19 was also $a+b < n+c\log\log n$

Comment: @MishaLavrov you should try to see if there are examples with $a+b = n+\Omega(\log n)$.

Comment: The confusion probably arises from the fact that the question title has $a + b$ on the l.h.s. of the inequality but the problem statement has only $b$ there.

Comment: @TravisWillse no. the OP asked about $a+b < n +c\log\log n$ but also linked to a question with just $b$ on the LHS

Comment: By "problem statement" I meant the problem as stated by Erdos, not OP's language. (To me their wording makes it ambiguous what OP's real question is.)